# How to properly parse string into integer inside JSONParser?

Tags: android, json, parsing

i have this code to retrieve my values in the database:

```
            if(json != null){
            try{
                result = json.getJSONArray("monthly");
                if(!result.toString().equals("[]")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject source = result.getJSONObject(i);
                        String month = source.getString("month");
                        String counted = source.getString("counted");

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), month, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
```

notice the

> String month = source.getString("month");

it is quick to return that value which just loads after 2 seconds or so. but when i try to parse that value into integer using this code:

> int month = Integer.parseInt(source.getString("month"));

it takes very long time to finish. so what im asking is how do you properly parse that data into an integer?

Edit:
JSON

> {"monthly":[{"month":"2","counted":"1"},{"month":"3","counted":"1"},{"month":"4","counted":"1"},{"month":"5","counted":"5"},{"month":"6","counted":"2"},{"month":"7","counted":"3"},{"month":"8","counted":"1"},{"month":"9","counted":"2"},{"month":"10","counted":"1"},{"month":"11","counted":"3"},{"month":"12","counted":"2"}]}

Comment: There's no alternative than getInt or optInt... Read the documentation

Comment: Checking `equals("[]")` is pointless, by the way. You already check the array length

Answer (score 0):

You can use getInt on the JSONObject:

```
source.getInt("month")
```

Performance is always an issue though when parsing data and depending on size could make quite an impact.  If you are trying to do this on the UI thread, you shouldn't.  Instead use some background thread.  AsyncTask is the Android specific way to run code on a background thread and then pass the results back to the UI thread.

Edit:

This is the code I have and there is no significant performance impact using getString vs. getInt so there must be an issue some place else in your code.

```
    try {
        JSONObject json =
            new JSONObject("{'monthly':[{'month':'2','counted':'1'},{'month':'3','counted':'1'},{'month':'4','counted':'1'},{'month':'5','counted':'5'},{'month':'6','counted':'2'},{'month':'7','counted':'3'},{'month':'8','counted':'1'},{'month':'9','counted':'2'},{'month':'10','counted':'1'},{'month':'11','counted':'3'},{'month':'12','counted':'2'}]}");
        JSONArray result = json.getJSONArray("monthly");
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject source = result.getJSONObject(i);
            int month = source.getInt("month");
            String counted = source.getString("counted");

            Toast.makeText(this,
                           "" + month,
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                 .show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i also tried the getInt but also takes time to load. i dont know how long because it has not finished loading

Comment: You should probably post your json too then.

Comment: I just had a thought that maybe your try catch block is masking the true issue that you are having.  Are you doing a catch all in your exception block rather than only catching the JSONException?  If you are trying to Toast with an int, you will more than likely get a Resource Not Found exception.